# Is it possible to enable lightning on a profile but have new users default to classic?

Tags: lightning, defaults, classic

I couldn't find anything on this option.  I would like to enable all users in a profile to have lightning available for use but still default users to classic until the conversion is made.  I appreciate any help with this request.  Thank you!

Comment: Do you also want the users not to be able even to see the Lightning Switcher or that still being available, but Users defaulting to Classic works?

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked out the salesforce documentation on which users should be using Lightning and how to go about setting up the users? Please see the link below:

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=lex_enable_users.htm&type=5

To get to the page where you can configure the settings, you have to first make sure your account is on Lightning. Then go to **Setup** and then type "Lightning Experience" into the search box in the top left corner. Click on  **Lightning Experience** and that will bring you to the page where you can learn whether you org is ready to switch to Lightning and the best practice of setting that up. There's even a trailhead module created for that! =)

[image: Set up Lightning Experience]